# Sistema de abas em CSS com 2 linhas de abas - código usando "float"

Tags: html, css

Estou usando o código abaixo para um formulário com múltiplas "abas", e eu gostaria que as abas 1-4 aparecessem acima das abas 5-8, em duas linhas. Porém, as abas 1-4 aparecem normalmente, mas as abas 5-8 ficam truncadas, elas não aparecem na linha de baixo como eu esperaria por serem "float".

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a mudar o código, para que as abas 5-8 aparecessem abaixo das abas 1-4, como nesta imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o código:

```css
.nav_tabs{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_tabs ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_tabs ul li{
  float: left;
}

.tab_label{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: solid 1px #A4A4A4;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_tabs .rd_tab { 
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav_tabs .rd_tab:checked ~ label { 
  background-color: #08298A;
  color:#fff;
  border: none;
}

.tab-content{
  border-top: solid 5px #08298A;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 420px;
  left: 40px; 
}

.rd_tab:checked ~ .tab-content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio"  class="rd_tab" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
      <label for="tab1" class="tab_label">ABA 1</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
          Conteúdo Aba 1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab2" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab2" class="tab_label">ABA 2</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 2  
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab3" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab3" class="tab_label">ABA 3</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 3   
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab4" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab4" class="tab_label">ABA 4</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 4  
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab5" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab5" class="tab_label">ABA 5</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 5  
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab6" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab6" class="tab_label">ABA 6</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 6  
      </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab7" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab7" class="tab_label">ABA 7</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 7  
      </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab8" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab8" class="tab_label">ABA 8</label>
      <div class="tab-content">  
        Conteúdo Aba 8  
      </div>
    </li>  
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lista inferior não está sendo exibida, por que o conteudo das abas superiores estão sobrepondo elas.

Então será necessário os conteúdos para fora da `ul`, porém ao fazer isto, não será possível alterar a visibilidade do conteúdo apenas utilizando `CSS`.

Segundo ponto, devido à um "bug" do `float:left`, é necessario aplicar um `clearfix` para que a `ul` tenha o seu tamanho corrigido.

O ultimo ajuste, foi apenas nas margens da `ul`, para aproximar o conteúdo da mesma.

Assim como aplicar um `box-sizing` às labels para deixar as bordas harmoniosas.

```js
var atual;
var contents = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tab]")
var onRadioChange = function (event) {
  if (atual) atual.content.classList.toggle("show", atual.radio.checked)
  this.content.classList.toggle("show", this.radio.checked)
  atual = this
};

[].forEach.call(contents, function (content) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.content = content
  obj.radio = document.getElementById(content.dataset.tab)
  obj.radio.addEventListener("change", onRadioChange.bind(obj))
  if (obj.radio.checked) {  
    obj.radio.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
  }
})
```

```css
.nav_tabs{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_tabs ul:before,
.nav_tabs ul:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.nav_tabs ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.nav_tabs ul{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_tabs ul li{  
  float: left;
}

.tab_label{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 105px;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: solid 1px #A4A4A4;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_tabs .rd_tab { 
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav_tabs .rd_tab:checked ~ label { 
  background-color: #08298A;
  color:#fff;
  border: none;
}

.tab-content{
  border-top: solid 5px #08298A;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 420px;
  left: 40px; 
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

.tab-content.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_tabs">  
  <ul>
    <li>    
      <input type="radio"  class="rd_tab" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
      <label for="tab1" class="tab_label">ABA 1</label>      
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab2" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab2" class="tab_label">ABA 2</label>      
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab3" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab3" class="tab_label">ABA 3</label>
      
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab4" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab4" class="tab_label">ABA 4</label>
      
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab5" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab5" class="tab_label">ABA 5</label>
      
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab6" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab6" class="tab_label">ABA 6</label>
      
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab7" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab7" class="tab_label">ABA 7</label>
      
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="rd_tab" id="tab8" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab8" class="tab_label">ABA 8</label>      
    </li>  
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab1">
      Conteúdo Aba 1
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab2">  
      Conteúdo Aba 2  
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab3">  
      Conteúdo Aba 3   
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab4">  
      Conteúdo Aba 4  
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab5">  
      Conteúdo Aba 5  
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab6">  
      Conteúdo Aba 6  
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab7">  
      Conteúdo Aba 7  
   </div>
   <div class="tab-content" data-tab="tab8">  
      Conteúdo Aba 8  
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: "ao fazer isto, não será possível alterar a visibilidade do conteúdo apenas utilizando CSS." - Não é bem assim, postei uma alternativa que faz exatamente isso. O segredo é separar os radiobuttons juntos, já que o label for é "remoto". Sua idéia é boa, mas o fato de manter o input com o label é que inviabilizou.

Comment: @Bacco eu pensei nesta possibilidade, mas não teria como aplicar um estilo ao label associado a radio selecionado.

Comment: a solução desta resposta parece ter um bug, porque quando clicamos mas abas da linha inferior - "ABAS 5-8", o conteúdo não troca para "Conteúdo Aba 5, 6, 7, 8.."

Comment: @RomuloRocha corrigido.

Comment: obrigado @TobiasMesquita ficou muito bom!

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução bem simples é separar os UL dos conteúdos e respectivos checkboxes.

A base é o exemplo abaixo, não estilizei para você ver claramente que o conteúdo "flutua" e funciona não importa o número de abas e nem de linhas (até forcei a quebra com `<br>` para facilitar o entendimento):

```css
.aba > input {display:none}
.aba > input + div {display:none}
.aba > input:checked + div {display:block}
```

```html
<label for="conteudo1">ABA1</label>
<label for="conteudo2">ABA2</label>
<label for="conteudo3">ABA3</label><br>
<label for="conteudo4">ABA4</label>
<label for="conteudo5">ABA5</label>
<label for="conteudo6">ABA6</label><br>
<label for="conteudo7">ABA7</label>
<label for="conteudo8">ABA8</label>
<label for="conteudo9">ABA9</label><br>

<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo1" name="abas"><div>Um</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo2" name="abas"><div>Dois</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo3" name="abas"><div>Tres</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo4" name="abas"><div>Quatro</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo5" name="abas"><div>Cinco</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo6" name="abas"><div>Seis</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo7" name="abas"><div>Sete</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo8" name="abas"><div>Oito</div></div>
<div class="aba"><input type="radio" id="conteudo9" name="abas"><div>Nove</div></div>
```

O código acima é uma base bem limpa, mas como está tudo separado, você é totalmente livre para estilizar e reestruturar o HTML para praticamente qualquer situação. A restrição é não ter como estilizar a aba selecionada. Para isto, veja a seguir:

### Usando o seletor `~` e estilizando a aba selecionada

Se quiser estilizar a aba selecionada, melhor manter o *radiobutton* junto da aba. Neste caso, o seletor geral `~` de irmão ajuda:

```css
.abas input {display:none}
.abas input:checked + label {color:red}
.abas .conteudo {display:none}

#aba1:checked ~ .c1,
#aba2:checked ~ .c2,
#aba3:checked ~ .c3,
#aba4:checked ~ .c4
  {display:block}
```

```html
<div class="abas">
  <input type="radio" name="abas" id="aba1"><label for="aba1">ABA1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="abas" id="aba2"><label for="aba2">ABA2</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="abas" id="aba3"><label for="aba3">ABA3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="abas" id="aba4"><label for="aba4">ABA4</label>
  <br>----------<br>
  <div class="conteudo c1">Um</div>
  <div class="conteudo c2">Dois</div>
  <div class="conteudo c3">Tres</div>
  <div class="conteudo c4">Quatro</div>
 </div>
```

Neste caso os pontos "contra" é que as `div`s de conteúdo tem que estar no mesmo nível dos `input`s, pois o seletor `~` não vai funcionar com aninhamento, e para evitar muita complexidade nos seletores, preferi deixar cada aba com uma classe separada. Provavelmente não seria escalável para 1000 abas num HTML feito à mão, mas provavelmente não vai acontecer numa situação real, e se acontecer, quase certeza que estará gerando o HTML dinamicamente, o que simplifica tudo.